# correlated query in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, correlated-subquery

I have three tables :

```
Rent
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| title | copy_num | member_id | date |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| ...   |...       |...        |...   |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Book
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|title   | publisher| writer | publish_date |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| ...    |...       |...     |...           |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Member
+++++++++++++++++++++
| id | name | phone |
+++++++++++++++++++++
| ...|...   |...    |
+++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to find for each member the publisher that he rents his pulished books the most. For example if a member rents more books published by Hachette the result should be a row indicating that fact. The results table for all the members should be something like :

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| member_name | member_phone | favorite_publisher |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
| memberX     | 562214894    | Hachette           |
| ...         | ...          | ...                |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I was able to do that for a specific member that has the id: 11111111 for example and without the phone number using this query:

```
SELECT id,
  publisher
FROM Rent R,
  Book B
WHERE R.member_id='11111111'
AND B.title     =R.title
GROUP BY member_id,
  publisher
HAVING COUNT(*)=
  (SELECT MAX(counter)
  FROM
    (SELECT member_id,
      publisher,
      COUNT(*) AS counter
    FROM Rent R,
      Book B
    WHERE R.member_id='11111111'
    AND B.title     =R.title
    GROUP BY member_id,
      publisher
    )
  ) ;
```

I do not want to use PL-SQL to iterate on the above query. I want to use just SQL, but i do not know how i can create a correlated subquery so i can do it for each member.

Edit 1: I do not want to use analytical functions to solve the problem. I want to solve the problem using just joins and correlated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Note: I have tested as I don't have sample data. You may need to modify a little bit.

```
select member_name, member_phone, Title, Rent_Count
from
(
    select m.member_name, m.member_phone, r.Title
    ,(
        select count(title)
        from Book
        where title = r.title
    ) as Rent_Count
    from Member m
    inner join Rent r on (r.member_id = m.id)
) r
order by Rent_Count desc
```

Comment: It is not the solution i am seeking and your most extern query has no sence and it can be deleted without a problem. The entire query just gives me a result similar to a simple join of the three tables and rent_count has the value: 1 in every row.

Answer (score 0):

This query will find out the count of publishers for a particular member from `rent` table and then find the max of count to get the desired result.

Give a try

```
 SELECT m.NAME       member_name,
       m.phone      member_phone,
       cq.publisher favorite_publisher
  FROM (SELECT COUNT(1) cc,
               MAX(COUNT(1)) over(PARTITION BY member_id) maxc,
               a.member_id,
               b.publisher
          FROM rent a
         INNER JOIN book b ON a.title = b.title
         GROUP BY a.member_id,
                  b.publisher) cq
 INNER JOIN MEMBER m ON m.id = cq.member_id
 WHERE maxc = cc;
```

Comment: You are using "over" and "partition by", and i want a solution that does not use PL-SQL, just simple SQL query.

Comment: This isn't PL-SQL, its simple SQL using Analytical Function.

Comment: OK, i was confused between PL/SQL and analytical functions, but what if i do not want to use analytical functions ? is it possible to solve the problem using just joins and correlated subqueries ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this readily in Oracle using the `keep`/`first` command. (Read all about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm).) This uses a subquery to calculate the counts for each member/publisher and then a second level to retain the top publisher:

```
select mp.name, mp.phone,
       max(mp.publisher) keep (dense_rank first order by cnt desc) as favorite_publisher
from (select m.name, m.phone, b.publisher, count(*) as cnt
      from member m join
           rent r
           on r.member_id = m.member_id join
           book b
           on r.title = b.title
      group by m.name, m.phone, b.publisher
     ) mp
group by mp.name, mp.phone;
```

Comment: I can not use PL-SQL. I am learning SQL and at this stage i can not use PL-SQL to make things easier.

Comment: @YoussefKhloufi . . . What are you referring to?  This is a standard Oracle query that doesn't use any PL/SQL-specific constructs.

Comment: OK, i was confused between PL/SQL and analytical functions, but what if i do not want to use analytical functions ? is it possible to solve the problem using just joins and correlated subqueries ?

Comment: Yes, but there is no reason to do that.

Comment: For me yes there is a reason, because i want to learn sql to do complex things before starting to learn the analytical functions and PL/SQL that can simplify things.